# How to locate the first occurrence of a string in a string

Tags: c, string, c99, c89

I need a function like memchr() but it should be able to locate a substring(string), **not an only single char.**
And it should return the first occurrence found in string.

For example

```
p1 = afunclikememchr(str1,"here the function that can locate this substring",200);
```

To the mods: I added the C++ tag because this is also relevant to C++

**In a nutshell:** I want a function that would be called `memstr()`, conventionally.

In addition, I must use C standard libraries, not C++, and the function should not stop when it founds a `'\0'` byte.

Comment: Would strstr work for you? http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr

Comment: What's wrong with [strstr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) ?

Comment: std::search does what you want.

Comment: I considered strstr() but it stops whenever it founds a '\0'

Comment: This isn't *relevant* to C++ at all and the fact that you only want to use the C library doesn't help your case.

Comment: "I must use C standard libraries not C++", "I added the C++ tag because this is also relevant to C++". Contradiction much?

Comment: Using `memcmp()` it should be easy and could be fun to roll your own.

Comment: Gnu has the `memmem(const void *haystack, size_t haystacklen,
                    const void *needle, size_t needlelen);` extension, which does not require either of the strings to be NUL terminated. If *one* of them is NUL terminated: `strlen()` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered strstr()?

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strstr.html

> The strstr() function shall locate the first occurrence in the string
>   pointed to by s1 of the sequence of bytes (excluding the terminating
>   null byte) in the string pointed to by s2.

Comment: Yes but it stops whenever it founds a '\0'

Comment: If there is a `\0` _in it_ it is **not a string**, by definition. A string terminates at (just before) the first `\0` Maybe you should rephrase your questio a bit? (there is no `\0` in the example string)

Answer (score 0):

<s>Since you tagged this question with both `c` and `c++` (which is wrong), I'm exploiting this fact to answer it as if it was a C question (I don't know if it really is):</s>

So you are looking for something like [`memstr()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=memstr) which is not a standard function, but I have an implementation [here](https://github.com/H2CO3/libsprec/blob/master/src/flac_encoder.c#L190-202).

Or just use the GNU extension [`memmem()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188914/c-searching-for-a-string-in-a-file), if available and you don't mind being non-standard.

Comment: Thanks for answer I added this because you can use C libraries in C++ projects.

Comment: But is there any other methods comes with ANSI C ?

Comment: But strlen stops if I have '\0' in substring
size_t needlesize = strlen(needle);
Consider this:
Substring: const char pattern[35] = {0x73,0x00,0x65,0x00,0x6E,0x00,0x64,0x00,0x75,0x00,0x73,0x00,0x65,0x00,0x72,0x00,0x6E,0x00,0x61,0x00,0x6D,0x00,0x65};

Comment: @user2400925 I suggest you look up the meaning of the words "haystack" and "needle" in a dictionary. Then you will get it. I have understood your question, and my `memstr()` function does exactly what you want. You just have to call it properly.

Comment: Ok I will try to do.
But do you have any explasion or thoughts about why the creators of C libraries did not added this simple function?
I think it is as simple as strstr()

Comment: @user2400925: `strXXx` functions work on C-strings only -- zero terminated. `memXXx` functions work on raw bytes. Your requirement falls between them, and is unlikely to come up on a regular basis. Use `memchr` to locate a possible first character inside a range (minus the search atring length), then use `strcmp` to check it's a match.

Comment: @user2400925 Honestly, I have no idea, and that question is out of scope (off-topic) here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need the equivalent of strstr which will work on general arrays.  This is what I assume from your question.  There is no memstr as you probably have found so you will have to write your own.

Something like this:

```
size_t memstr(const unsigned char* arr, size_t length, const unsigned char* tofind, size_t flength) {
   for(size_t i = 0; i < length-flength; ++i) {
      if(memcmp(arr+i, tofind, flength) == 0)
         return i;
   }

   return -1;  //highest possible unsigned value - eg std::string::npos often implemented like this.
}


int main() {
   const unsigned char arr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4};
   size_t sz = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]);
   const unsigned char fnd[] = {3,3,3};

   size_t where = memstr(arr1, sz, fnd, 3);
   return 0;
}
```