# How to check if a string is in a binary file

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fread, strstr, fgetc

i am making a program that gets two binary files, and checks if the second file (string) is in the first file.
I tried to use strstr function but it doesnt work. This is that part of my code:
Am i reading the files right?

```
    fseek(fileToCheckv, 0 , SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fileToCheckv);
    rewind(fileToCheckv);
    fseek(virusSignit, 0L, SEEK_END);
    vsize = ftell(virusSignit);
    rewind(virusSignit);
    buffer = (char*)realloc(buffer, size+1 * sizeof(char));
    virusSig = (char*)realloc(virusSig, vsize+1 * sizeof(char));
    buffer[size] = 0;
    virusSig[vsize] = 0;
    fread(buffer,1 , size, fileToCheckv);
    fread(virusSig,1 ,vsize, virusSignit);
    result = strstr(buffer, virusSig);
    if (result != NULL)
    {
        printf("\nVirus was found in file: %s\n", fileToOpen);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The virus was not found\n");
    }
```

Comment: _size+1 * sizeof(char)_ == size + sizeof(char)... I guess that is not what you meant

Comment: Of course `strstr` wont work because it operates on NUL terminated strings. You need to write your own "binbin" function having e.g. this signature: `char *binbin(const char *needle, const char *haystack, int length)`. I didn't check for other issues though.

Comment: Since the fread will copy the data into a char array that has a 0 in it's end, won't this be just as NUL terminated strings?

Comment: @CIsForCookies the binary data itself could contain NUL bytes anywhere.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I see... but in case with strings not containing NUL bytes, this will work, wouldn't it?

Comment: @CIsForCookies yes.

Comment: @MichaelWalz There is the memmem() function, which is basically strstr(), but allowing NULs in the "strings". It has **four** arguments, two pointers and two sizes. NOTE: *This function is a GNU extension.*

Comment: Thank you! Can i use the memmem() function in windows?

Comment: @joop `memmem` is a gnu extension. It doesn't exist on Windows, but it's not very hard to rewrite.

Comment: @user8097385 [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188914/c-searching-for-a-string-in-a-file) may help.

Comment: In C a _string_ is a sequence of characters up to and including a ending _null chracter_.  With _binary_ files, "checks if the second file is in the first file." does not make sense as the second files contents may not constitute a _string_.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the files correctly, but you have some other minor issues:

- `buffer = (char*)realloc(buffer, size+1 * sizeof(char));`. You probably meant to do `(size+1) * sizeof(char)` of simply `size+1` as sizeof(char) will be always 1. This problem occurs twice in your code
- In the same line' you use `realloc` without checking if the pointer is NULL. That could prove problematic if you allocation fails
- As @Michael Walz said, `strstr()` is for NUL-terminated strings, so for binary you should either create your own `strstr`-like function for binary, or verify there aren't NUL-bytes in your strings